# How to put 'Acceptance' below submit button? Elementor Pro Form + Inline input problems

Tags: wordpress, forms, elementor

I am trying to do a newsletter form as shown below with Elementor Pro in wordpress.

[image]

I know that to make the fields inline, you should set the width to less than 100%, in my case I set it to 50% for email and 50% for the submit button. But they do not appear inline. I turned Labels off as that was a way to inline them better but it is not working for me. What else should I try?

[image]

And finally, I added the 'Acceptance' field type in my form, but in order to make it look like in first snippet I provided, it means that the field should come after the Submit button. How does that work? The button is in another section on the widget and I cannot reorder them by dragging. Also, why isn't the text inline with the checkbox?
[image]

I would really appreciate any feedback, I am very new to wordpress.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your problems but I cannot - at least the part about the button and input field being inline. That's why it's probably a styling related issue with your theme.

The acceptance-field is different. It is rendered that way by the plugin but with a tiny piece of css you can change it. Just put this in your **advanced -> custom css** field

```
.elementor-field-type-acceptance {
    order: 1;
}
```

in my case it looks like this
[image]